# Python Gaussian curve fitting gives straight line, supplied amplitude of y

Tags: python, scipy, astropy

I am trying to fit a gaussian distribution to some data I have, the data depicts variation in density with height. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting

x = heights
y = densities

#calculate fit parameters
n = len(x) #no. of obs
mean = sum(x*y)/n #average
sigma = sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n #std dev
amplitude = max(y)

g_init = models.Gaussian1D(amplitude, mean, sigma)
fit_g = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
g = fit_g(g_init, x, y)

plt.plot(heights, densities)
plt.plot(x, g(x), label='Gaussian')

#plot labels

plt.xlabel("Height[km]")
plt.ylabel("Density")
plt.show()
```

However, the plot of the gaussian is just a straight line. Please help me figure out how to correct this. I searched, and the problem seems to be that it is not converging, so I supplied the amplitude as max(y).. but it won't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to try and use a weighted mean and sigma as starting points, but you may need to divide by `sum(y)` instead of `n` in that case. Compare your currently calculated mean and sigma with the actual distribution (i.e., without any fitting): does that look correct?

Comment: Oh, I see. I substituted n with sum(y) and it worked.. thanks!